# upgrading postfix 2.11 to 3.3.0- localhost.localdomain causing issues

Tags: postfix, virtual-hosting

I attempted to upgrade a working mail server from Ubuntu 14.04 to 18.04, and cant work out what is causing failures related to the sender: field being populated with "...localhost.localdomain" in the upgraded system.  (The old system works fine)

I have, among others, the following settings

```
mydomain = networksavvy.org
myhostname = mail.networksavvy.org
myorigin = $myhostname
```

Some emails appear to be sent OK, and some appear to be receiving, but I suspect that the issue has to do with virtualhosts.

An example highlighting the issue:  I set up email address on another mail system to forward from an off-site server back to this server.  When I send an email to that address, the second server accepts the mail, but fails to forward it on.  When I look at the mail queue I see the following line, which I am fairly sure is representative of the problem:

```
sender: SRS0=tFlT=XJ=mydomain.com=duser@localhost.localdomain
```

however the following also exist

```
original_recipient: addr@system2.com
recipient: user@domain.com
From: user@mydomain.com
```

The error when the remote mail server tries to send email back is

```
Status: host mail.mydomain.com[X.X.X.X] said: 450 4.1.8 <SRS0=tFlT=XJ=networksavvy.org=user@localhost.localdomain>: Sender address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command)
```

Edit:
I do note that I am running postsrsd, and wonder if this relates to anything.

Questions:

1. Where does the sender: field come into things?
2. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was running postsrsd, and this self-configured to use localhost.localdomain.  Restarting this with the correct "-d" parameter fixed the issue.